# Is it really a reduction?

Tags: redox

In my chemistry book they write $\ce{MnO4^- -> Mn^{2+}}$ is a reduction but is this correct? Electrons are lost aren't they because it becomes less negative so is it not an oxidation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple analogy to see whether oxidation or reduction has occur is as following.
If oxidation number of element decreases,there will be reduction and if oxidation number increases there will be oxidation.In your case,Mn had +7 oxidation state initially  and finally it has a oxidation state of +2 so it is a reduction.

Comment: So how does your technique work with hydrogen peroxide?

Comment: in peroxides,oxygen atom always have -1 oxidation state.

Answer (score 6):

You have to write out the complete half-cell reaction, and then it is obvious that $\ce{MnO4^−}$ is reduced.

$\ce{MnO4^− + 8 H^+ + 5 e^− <=>[reduction][oxidation] Mn^{2+} + 4H2O\quad\quad\quad\rm{E}^0 = +1.51~\rm{V}}$